# Setting ticks on 3-D plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm doing some cluster analysis and want to use matplotlib to visualize the results. For the most part, this is working out OK. However, I'm struggling with controlling tick placement on the axes. That is, the ticks on the y axis are overcrowded and I'd like to thin them out. I've tried supplying a range for the ticks using the numpy arrange function, but this isn't working.

I don't know if this is because I'm not familiar enough with matplotlib, or if it's an issue with 3-D plotting. In any event, I've tried all the solutions I can find on Stack and nothing seems to be working.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(data['col_1'], data['col_2'], data['col_3'], c = data.index,  cmap = cm.winter, s=60)
ax.view_init(15, 240)
ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z- Axis')
plt.title('Sample Plot')
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot has bunched up numbers on y-axis]

My solution to this is to supply the ticks as follows:

```
ticks = np.arange(0.3, 0.7, 0.02)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(data['col_1'], data['col_2'], data['col_3'], c = data.index,  cmap = cm.winter, s=60)
ax.view_init(15, 240)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_zticks(ticks)
ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z- Axis')
plt.title('Sample Bad Plot')
plt.show()
```

However, this only produces the hot mess below. Any help to be had?
[image: This is the resulting mess]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your x-values lie approximately within the range `0.54-0.68`, your y-values lie within the range `0.34-0.42` and your z-values lie within the range`0.55-0.63`. Now in your second code, you define `ticks = np.arange(0.3, 0.7, 0.02)` which creates ticks from `0.3` to `0.68` and then you assign these values to be displayed on x, y, z axis using `ax.set_xticks(ticks)` and so on. You get this mess because your supplied `ticks` values are outside the range of actual x, y, z data points. Since you are only interested in refining the `y` axis ticks, you can just do

`ticks = np.arange(0.34, 0.44, 0.02)`

and then just set the ticks for the `y` axis as

`ax.set_yticks(ticks)`.

If you don't want to specify the numbers `0.34` and `0.44` manually, you can find the maximum and minimum `y` value and use something like `ticks = np.arange(min_value, max_value, 0.02)`.

Since I do not have access to your original data `data['col_1']` and so on, I can't play with your code but the above tips will surely help.

Comment: Nice one! This solves the problem in one go. Thanks very much indeed––it's appreciated!